# How can I pop up the virtual keyboard without using the textfield in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Is there any program code that can help me to pop up the virtual keyboard without using the textfield? Also, how can I get the character typed by users through the virtual keyboard ? Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display keyboard for your custom UI element you need to make it a `UIResponder` subclass (so any `UIView` subsclass will do) that conforms to [UIKeyInput](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIKeyInput) protocol and make it firstResponder.

One of the required methods in that protocol is `insertText:` where you can get each character that user types

You can find example of how that method can be used [here](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/04/21/iphone-os-3-2-uikeyinput-example/)

Comment: Sorry, could you give me the code in detail or some useful link about it since I am the beginner of Xcode? Thank you so much!